# What is the difference between Worn, Readied and Other Items?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, objects, encumbrance

In the official character sheet of Pathfinder 2e, the Inventory is divided into three lists: "WORN ITEMS", "READIED ITEMS" and "OTHER ITEMS". What is the difference between them?

I'm specifically interested in what is the maximum you can have of each.

Maybe the "worn"s are in the backpack (so 1 action to remove the backpack, 1 for extracting = 2 actions), and the "ready" is over your body (in belts and pouches) so they only cost 1 action the get them.

Answer (score 6):

### I think the character sheet is designed different from the rule text

Nobody the Hobgoblin's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208609/28326) assumes parity between the [Carrying and Using Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=186) rules (held, worn, and stowed, and wielded) and the character sheet design (worn, readied, and other). I don't think this was the intent, and **I would use the character sheet differently.** And I think that's the crux of this answer; the character sheet *isn't a rules element* and is *just a tool*. It is made for ease of use, not as a reminder of the other rules. For the default character sheet, this is how I would use the various spaces:

- **Worn items** are *not* "items are tucked into pockets, belt pouches, bandoliers, weapon sheaths, and so forth" but are actually the [Worn Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=41) the character currently has on, and possibly weapon(s)/shields(s).
- **Readied items** are the items a character is 'wearing' per the Carrying rules - consumables and up to 2 Bulk of [Tool kits](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1456) they can retrieve with a single action or as part of a skill action using the Tools.
- **Other items** is everything else, the stuff they have 'stowed' per the Carrying rules. That would be various adventuring supplies, plot items, and such that they would not need quick access to (as well as consumables they want to be a little more safe than 'in a belt pouch'). Items would have to be in this category to benefit from the [backpack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=4) item, or to negate their Bulk by being in a [Bag of Holding](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=249) or similar.

There is no formal limit to the number of equipment pieces you can wear (other than your Investment limiting the number of magic items you can use at once) and the guidance that you can *usually* only have one piece [Worn](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=699) on certain parts of your body (e.g. you can usually only have one cloak, one pair of shoes, one pair of gloves, etc.). There is also no formal limit on the number of pieces of equipment you can 'wear' readied... except that they are not in your [Backpack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=4) or [Bag of Holding](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=249), so they apply to your [encumbrance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=188) directly.

---

User [ESCE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/64464/esce) also points out that a good way to organize items is based on Actions to retrieve; Worn - 0 Actions (it's already there); Readied - 1 Action (it's in a known place on your adventuring gear); Other - 2(+) Actions (you have to go digging for it, such as removing your pack). This is both functional and essentially lines up with my interpretation above.

Comment: I think you are right, this is a useful approach, using quick access items for "Readied items", instead of wielded items that change more often. The rules of course do not explicitly specify, so you could do it either way, but that is really up to the user of the character sheet, not a rules question. +1

Comment: fwiw, I've been using them per number of actions needed to get them (Worn = 0, Readied = 1 so includes weapons/shields, Other = 2+), and have found that to be very effective in organizing my character and helpful in combat.

Answer (score 5):

### Mainly it's about how fast you can access them

[Carrying and Using Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=186) says:

> A character carries items in three ways: **held, worn, and stowed**. Held items are in your hands; a character typically has two hands, allowing them to hold an item in each hand or a single two-handed item using both hands. Worn items are tucked into pockets, belt pouches, bandoliers, weapon sheaths, and so forth, and they can be retrieved and returned relatively quickly. Stowed items are in a backpack or a similar container, and they are more difficult to access.

And [Wielding Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194) further elaborates:

> Some abilities require you to wield an item, typically a weapon. You're wielding an item any time you're holding it in the number of hands needed to use it effectively. When wielding an item, you're not just carrying it around—**you're ready to use it**. Other abilities might require you to be wearing the item, to be holding it, or simply to have it.

So the straightforward way to map these is:

- **Worn Items**: items that are **worn**, and that need no time or actions to access. Worn items are all items [you wear](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=699), such as clothing, rings and armor, details below.
- **Readied Items**: items that are ready to use, i.e. **wielded**, you can put for example the weapon there that you typically carry in hand. Don't ask me why there is so much space for these -- maybe to record defaults for different circumstances? As [@ESCE points out in a comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208608/what-is-the-difference-between-worn-readied-and-other-items#comment572868_208611), another approach that works well practically, is to put items there that can be accessed with an action cost of only 1 action, like sheathed weapons or a shield.
- **Other Items**: Items that are neither worn nor wielded, but **stowed**, and not that easily accessed, e.g. stuff in your backpack.

#### Limits on numbers of each type

> An item that needs to be worn to function lists “worn” as its usage. This is followed by another word if the character is limited to only one of that type of item. For instance, a character can wear any number of rings, so the entry for a ring would list only “worn.” However, if the Usage entry were “worn cloak,” then a character couldn’t wear another cloak on top of that one. It’s assumed that items are meant to be worn by humanoids; any item that can or must be worn by a different type of creature either states this in its description or has the companion trait.

There is no overall limit on the number of mundane worn items (other than the weight you can carry, and that you may not wear two cloaks or such). For worn *magic* items the core rules say (as does the character sheet itself) under [Worn Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=768):

> This section includes magic items you wear. Most have the invested trait, which means you can wear no more than 10

The limit for readied items is your available hands, normally 2. Some items require both your hands to wield, so in effect you are limited to 1 or 2 of these.

The limit for stowed items is again just weight and maybe bulk, but there are no limits on numbers.